# Roslyn how to create a class with multiple Declaration Modifiers

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

I'm creating a code generator. to simplify the issue i'm having, how can I generate a class with multiple declaration modifiers?

The class Generator only has a constructor for adding a single Declaration Modifier

```
this._syntaxGenerator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(workspace, LanguageNames.CSharp);
var classNode = this._syntaxGenerator.ClassDeclaration(classOptions.Name, null, 
                      classOptions.InternalAccessModifier, DeclarationModifiers.Sealed)
                     .NormalizeWhitespace();
```

Say I wanted to create a sealed partial class or something with multiple Declaration Modifiers how can I do that?

Comment: Just try to use the some existing modifiers and recreate a new using `WithIs**`. It looks like this `var modifiers = DeclarationModifiers.Sealed.WithIsAbstract(true).WithIsStatic(true);
`. After that you only need to pass it into `SyntaxGenerator.ClassDeclaration`

Comment: Ah, okay I was hoping to be able to pass an array,l because I'm parsing it from text, I guess I'll have to convert everything to a token list instead.  If you post that as an answer I'll mark it correct

Comment: `DeclarationModifiers` override operators so you can sum modifiers by text using `Expression`. But I'm not sure that it will be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use the some existing modifiers and recreate a new using `WithIs**`. It looks like this:

```cs
var modifiers = DeclarationModifiers.Sealed.WithIsAbstract(true).WithIsStatic(true);
```

After that you only need to pass it into `SyntaxGenerator.ClassDeclaration`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the '|' operator to combine declaration modifiers:

DeclarationModifiers.Sealed | DeclarationModifiers.Abstract

just like with flag enums.

Comment: Thanks, parsing text to do this this is an easier way to get what I want executed